# using Youtube Data API without Google play service

Tags: android, youtube, google-play-services

I have a question about GooglePlayService(com.google.android.gms)
Is it possible that using Youtube Data API without GooglePlayService?

my device is not installed GooglePlayService and GooglePlayStore.
but I have to use Youtube Data API.

Now using Youtube Data API below error Dialog is shown

'This app won't run without Google Play services, which are missing from your phone'

please reply my question.
thanks.

Comment: you can play via webview.

Comment: yes you can play this in webview by providing the url of video...

Answer (score 0):

Use this Fragment to display Youtube Videos in your App. This fragment class allows to :-

1. Play Videos in both Portrait & landscape Mode.
2. Give warning if user is trying to view video in offline.

Use this layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/images"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/customViewContainer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/alert_root"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_info_white_48dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Not Connected to Network"
            android:textColor="@color/actionbar_color"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

public class VideoFragment extends Fragment {

    /** The web view. */
    private WebView webView;

    /** The custom view container. */
    private FrameLayout customViewContainer;

    /** The custom view callback. */
    private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback customViewCallback;

    /** The m custom view. */
    private View mCustomView;

    /** The m web chrome client. */
    private myWebChromeClient mWebChromeClient;

    /** The m web view client. */
    private myWebViewClient mWebViewClient;

    /**
     * Instantiates a new video fragment.
     */
    public VideoFragment() {
        // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see
     * android.support.v4.app.Fragment#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,
     * android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.media_fragment, container,
                false);

        customViewContainer = (FrameLayout) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.customViewContainer);
        webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView);

        if (!Connectivity.isConnected(getActivity())) {

            webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            rootView.findViewById(R.id.alert_root).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog((GoDhamHomeActivity) getActivity());
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.connection_dialog);
            Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
            // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
            dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();

                }
            });

            dialog.show();

        } else {
            rootView.findViewById(R.id.alert_root).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            mWebViewClient = new myWebViewClient();
            webView.setWebViewClient(mWebViewClient);

            mWebChromeClient = new myWebChromeClient();
            webView.setWebChromeClient(mWebChromeClient);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
            webView.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC8EbZkPWGtOn1YGVSUzjaWw/videos");
        }

        rootView.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

                    if (inCustomView()) {
                        hideCustomView();
                        return true;
                    }

                    if ((mCustomView == null) && webView.canGoBack()) {
                        webView.goBack();
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                // return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
                return false;
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    /**
     * In custom view.
     *
     * @return true, if successful
     */
    public boolean inCustomView() {
        return (mCustomView != null);
    }

    /**
     * Hide custom view.
     */
    public void hideCustomView() {
        mWebChromeClient.onHideCustomView();
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.support.v4.app.Fragment#onPause()
     */
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause(); // To change body of overridden methods use File |
                            // Settings | File Templates.
        webView.onPause();
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.support.v4.app.Fragment#onResume()
     */
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume(); // To change body of overridden methods use File |
                            // Settings | File Templates.
        webView.onResume();
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.support.v4.app.Fragment#onStop()
     */
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop(); // To change body of overridden methods use File |
                        // Settings | File Templates.
        if (inCustomView()) {
            hideCustomView();
        }
    }

    // public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
    //
    // if (inCustomView()) {
    // hideCustomView();
    // return true;
    // }
    //
    // if ((mCustomView == null) && webView.canGoBack()) {
    // webView.goBack();
    // return true;
    // }
    // }
    // return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    // }

    /**
     * The Class myWebChromeClient.
     */
    class myWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

        /** The m default video poster. */
        private Bitmap mDefaultVideoPoster;

        /** The m video progress view. */
        private View mVideoProgressView;

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * 
         * @see
         * android.webkit.WebChromeClient#onShowCustomView(android.view.View,
         * int, android.webkit.WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback)
         */
        @Override
        public void onShowCustomView(View view, int requestedOrientation,
                CustomViewCallback callback) {
            onShowCustomView(view, callback); // To change body of overridden
                                                // methods use File | Settings |
                                                // File Templates.
        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * 
         * @see
         * android.webkit.WebChromeClient#onShowCustomView(android.view.View,
         * android.webkit.WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback)
         */
        @Override
        public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {

            // if a view already exists then immediately terminate the new one
            if (mCustomView != null) {
                callback.onCustomViewHidden();
                return;
            }
            mCustomView = view;
            webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            customViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            customViewContainer.addView(view);
            customViewCallback = callback;
        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * 
         * @see android.webkit.WebChromeClient#getVideoLoadingProgressView()
         */
        @Override
        public View getVideoLoadingProgressView() {

            if (mVideoProgressView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
                mVideoProgressView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_progress,
                        null);
            }
            return mVideoProgressView;
        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * 
         * @see android.webkit.WebChromeClient#onHideCustomView()
         */
        @Override
        public void onHideCustomView() {
            super.onHideCustomView(); // To change body of overridden methods
                                        // use File | Settings | File Templates.
            if (mCustomView == null)
                return;

            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            customViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // Hide the custom view.
            mCustomView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // Remove the custom view from its container.
            customViewContainer.removeView(mCustomView);
            customViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();

            mCustomView = null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * The Class myWebViewClient.
     */
    class myWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * 
         * @see
         * android.webkit.WebViewClient#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit
         * .WebView, java.lang.String)
         */
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url); // To change body
                                                                // of overridden
                                                                // methods use
                                                                // File |
                                                                // Settings |
                                                                // File
                                                                // Templates.
        }
    }

    public static Fragment newInstance() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new VideoFragment();
    }

}
```

use this method to check connectivity status:-

```
  public static boolean isConnected(Context context) {
        NetworkInfo info = Connectivity.getNetworkInfo(context);
        return (info != null && info.isConnected());
    }
```

Here is Dialog layout to display offline notification

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/images" 
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/godham_logo" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
        android:text="Look like you are Offline. \n For better experience use Application online"
        android:textColor="@color/actionbar_color"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialogButtonOK"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/green_g_plus_button"
        android:text="Ok Got it"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have Hosted project for this POC in github you can find complete project here

https://github.com/hiteshsahu/Android-Universal-Web-Content-Loader